# Создать "красивые" номера на java

Tags: java

Написал код который генерирует автомобильные номера в формате A234MH197. Подскажите как сделать только "красивые" номера? Пример А777МН197, то есть должно быть 3 парные цифры, 000, 111, 222, 333 и т.д, буквы могут быть разными.

```
class GenerationCarOfNumbers
{
    final char[] carLetters = {'А', 'В', 'Е', 'К', 'М', 'Н', 'О', 'Р', 'С', 'Т', 'У', 'Х'};
    final int MIN_VALUE_REGION = 1;
    final int MAX_VALUE_REGION = 199;
    final int MIN_VALUE_NUMBER_CAR = 0;
    final int MAX_VALUE_NUMBER_CAR = 10;

    String str = new String(carLetters);

    //общая работа
    public void addCarNumber()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            generateTheSecondLetterOfTheNumber();
            generateTheThirdLetterOfTheNumber();
            generateTheFirstLetterOfTheNumber();
            generationOfTheRegion();
            generationOfFiguresOfNumber();
            test();
        }
    }

    //первая буква номера
    public char generateTheSecondLetterOfTheNumber()
    {
        int X = (int) (Math.random() * str.length());
        //String testX = Character.toString(resultX);
        return carLetters[X];
    }

    //генерация цифр номера
    public int generationOfFiguresOfNumber()
    {
        return (int) ((Math.random() * (MAX_VALUE_NUMBER_CAR - MIN_VALUE_NUMBER_CAR)) + MIN_VALUE_NUMBER_CAR);
    }

    //вторая буква номера
    public char generateTheThirdLetterOfTheNumber()
    {
        int Y = (int) (Math.random() * str.length());
        //String testY = Character.toString(resultY);
        return carLetters[Y];
    }

    //третья буква номера
    public char generateTheFirstLetterOfTheNumber()
    {
        int Z = (int) (Math.random() * str.length());
        //String testZ = Character.toString(resultZ);
        return carLetters[Z];
    }

    //генерация региона
    public int generationOfTheRegion()
    {
        return (int) ((Math.random() * (MAX_VALUE_REGION - MIN_VALUE_REGION)) + MIN_VALUE_REGION);
    }

    //вызов на экран
    public void test()
    {
        String test1 = String.format("%s%d%d%d%s%s%d", generateTheSecondLetterOfTheNumber(),
                                     generationOfFiguresOfNumber(), generationOfFiguresOfNumber(),
                                     generationOfFiguresOfNumber(), generateTheThirdLetterOfTheNumber(),
                                     generateTheFirstLetterOfTheNumber(), generationOfTheRegion());
        System.out.println(test1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вместо генерации случайных цифр, подставляйте строки "000" "111" "222" ...

Comment: generationOfFiguresOfNumber() делаешь 1 раз и подставляешь на 2 3 цифру

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посидев подумав над этим заданием, я пришел к выводу что такой код не подходит для реализации данного задания, так как такой метод позволяет составить рваный метод номерного знака и нет уверенности что не будет пропущен какой то вариант "красивого" номера.

Получается что тут подходит только метод перебора циклами:

- Первый цикл перебирает буквы из массива и создает первую букву номера
- Второй цикл перебирает цифры от 0 до 9, потому что в номерах могут быть только такие цифры
- Третий и четвертый цикл перебирают массив с буквами и создают вторую и третью букву номера
- Пятый цикл перебирает цифры от 1 до 199, количество регионов в России.

Пример:

```
final String[] carLetters = new String[] {"А", "В", "Е", "К", "М", "Н", "О", "Р", "С", "Т", "У", "Х"};
for (String letter : carLetters) {
    for (int figure = 0; figure < 10; figure++) {
        for (String letter_2 : carLetters) {
            for (String letter_3 : carLetters) {
                for (int m = 1; m <= 199; m++) {
                    String numberCar = String.format("(%s)(%d%d%d)%s%s(%d)", letter, figure, figure, figure, letter_2, letter_3, m);
                    System.out.println(numberCar);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Выглядит, конечно, страшновато. Не пробовали переписать через Stream API?